How do I retrieve the result values from a Metal compute in Swift?
I have an algorithm written in pure Swift works but is slow, I’m converting to Metal
compute in the hopes of speeding it up. After calling the Metal compute function
the result is an array of 0s not an array of 1s.
Treat all Shavian variable names as poorly chosen names(ex: x1, x2, stuff … etc).
Variables that are not defined here are normal Swift variables and not seen by Metal.
There is a lot of Swift code that is not shown.
This is the Metal compute function, note the last line throws out any computed value to
force the result to be an array of 1s. This was done because the output was an array of 0s
and I wanted to force a known value for testing.
kernel void scale_weight(device const int* adjustment [[buffer(0)]],
                         device float& maximum        [[buffer(1)]],
                         device float& scale          [[buffer(2)]],
                         device bool&  inverse        [[buffer(3)]],
                         device float* result         [[buffer(4)]],
                         uint index [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    float my_adjust = inverse? (maximum - (float)adjustment[index]) :
                        (float)adjustment[index];
    result[index] += scale * my_adjust;
    result[index] = 1.0;
}

In the main Swift code:
guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
    fatalError("Metal device was not created.")
}

guard let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue() else {
    fatalError("Could not create command queue for GPU.")
}

guard let library:MTLLibrary = device.makeDefaultLibrary() else {
    fatalError("Device library was not created.")
}

guard let adjustFunc:MTLFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "scale_weight") else {
    fatalError("Could not find weight adjustment function.")
}

let pipeline:MTLComputePipelineState
do {
    pipeline = try device.makeComputePipelineState(function: adjustFunc)
} catch {
    fatalError("Could not create pipeline for GPU.")
}

typealias MetalStuff = (device:MTLDevice,
                        commandQueue:MTLCommandQueue,
                        pipeline:MTLComputePipelineState)

let metalStuff:MetalStuff = (device, commandQueue, pipeline)
...
let ·:MTXMapper = CountIt5(depth: , metalStuff:metalStuff)
let  = ·.encode(data: )

Properties defined in struct CountIt5:
let ·:[Float] =
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

var ·:Bool = true
var ··:MTLBuffer

var ·:Bool = false
var ··:MTLBuffer

var ·255:Float = 255.0
var ·255·:MTLBuffer

var ··:MTLBuffer
    
var ·:Float
var ··:MTLBuffer

var ·:Float
var ··:MTLBuffer

var :[Float]
var ·:MTLBuffer

let ms:MetalStuff

In CountIt5.init
init(depth :Int, metalStuff ms:MetalStuff,
     testWeight ·:Int = -1, attribute :Int = -1,
     depthTest ·:[Float]? = nil) {
...
    · = · / 255.0
    · = · / 255.0
...
    1 = OrderingGroup(delegate: OrderingMoveToFront(), count: 1)
...
    self.ms = ms
        
    if let · = ms.device.makeBuffer(bytes: &·,
                                           length: MemoryLayout<Bool>.stride,
                                           options: []) {
        ·· = ·
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not create inverse true buffer.")
    }

    if let · = ms.device.makeBuffer(bytes: &·,
                                           length: MemoryLayout<Bool>.stride,
                                           options: []) {
        ·· = ·
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not create inverse false buffer.")
    }

    if let · = ms.device.makeBuffer(bytes: &·255,
                                           length: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride,
                                           options: []) {
        ·255· = ·
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not create maximum 255 buffer.")
    }

    if let · = ms.device.makeBuffer(bytes: &1.[0].··,
                                           length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride,
                                           options: []) {
        ·· = ·
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not create order adjust buffer.")
    }

    if let · = ms.device.makeBuffer(bytes: &·,
                                           length: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride,
                                           options: []) {
        ·· = ·
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not create order scale buffer.")
    }

    if let · = ms.device.makeBuffer(bytes: &·,
                                           length: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride,
                                           options: []) {
        ·· = ·
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not create data scale buffer.")
    }

     = ·
    if let · = ms.device.makeBuffer(bytes: ,
                                           length: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * .count,
                                           options: []) {
        · = ·
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not create adjustment buffer.")
    }

1.[0].·· is a property of several nested Swift structs, it is defined as:
var ··:[Int32]

This is the code in CountIt5.encode:
1.updateOrdering(data: )

if let commandBuffer = ms.commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() {
    if let computeEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() {
        computeEncoder.setComputePipelineState(ms.pipeline)
        computeEncoder.setBuffer(··, offset: 0, index: 0)
        computeEncoder.setBuffer(·255·,   offset: 0, index: 1)
        computeEncoder.setBuffer(··,  offset: 0, index: 2)
        computeEncoder.setBuffer(··, offset: 0, index: 3)
        computeEncoder.setBuffer(·,   offset: 0, index: 4)
                
        let gridSize = MTLSize(width: .count, height: 1, depth: 1)
        let threadGroupSize = MTLSize(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1)
        computeEncoder.dispatchThreads(gridSize, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupSize)
                
        computeEncoder.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer.commit()
        commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
    }
}

The call to updateOrdering modifies the ·· array.
If I place a breakpoint just after the call to waitUntilCompleted then examine  every value in the array is 0 not the expected 1.
